# Row count of nested GridView is always zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Parent grid-view is `gvAgreement`.

Child grid-view is  `gvProducts`.

Code used :

```
protected void gvAgreement_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                string AgreementId = gvAgreement.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                GridView gvProducts = e.Row.FindControl("gvProducts") as GridView;
                gvProducts.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("SELECT dbo.Agreement.*, dbo.Agreementlist.*, dbo.Store.*, dbo.Agreementlist.Agreement_ID AS agreid FROM dbo.Agreement INNER JOIN dbo.Agreementlist ON dbo.Agreement.Agreement_ID = dbo.Agreementlist.Agreement_ID INNER JOIN dbo.Store ON dbo.Agreementlist.ProID = dbo.Store.Pro_ID WHERE (dbo.Agreementlist.Agreement_ID = '{0}')", AgreementId));
                gvProducts.DataBind();
                int count = gvProducts.Rows.Count;
               Session["countgrid"] = count;

            }

    }

protected void gvProducts_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
      if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["countgrid"].ToString()) == 1)
                    {
                        string message = "alert('Agreement at least must have one product');";
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(sender as Control, this.GetType(), "alert", message, true);
                    }
    }
```

I tried to define count as global value but it also gives zero.

Answer (score 0):

When / how do you databind the child grid? You should do it inside the OnRowDataBound event of the master grid as, presumably, its contents rely on the row of the master grid in which it is located.

```
protected void gvAgreement_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string AgreementId = gvAgreement.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            GridView gvProducts = e.Row.FindControl("gvProducts") as GridView;
            if(gvProducts != null)
            {
                  gvProducts.DataSource = [some query or data source here]
                  gvProducts.DataBind();
            }
            int count = gvProducts.Rows.Count;
            Session["countgrid"] = count;
        }

}
```

EDITED AFTER COMMENTS

You shouldn't store the row count in a session variable. You don't need to, because the place where you want to make use of it (in the RowCommand event), you can actually find out what it is.

Something like:

```
protected void gvProducts_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  var gvProducts = e.Row.FindControl("gvProducts") as GridView;
  if (gvProducts != null && gvProducts.Rows.Count < 1)
  {
      string message = "alert('Agreement must have at least one product');";
      ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(sender as Control, this.GetType(), "alert", message, true);
  }
```

Comment: i forgot to add gvProducts.DataSource to the post i still have the issue

Comment: are you sure that your datasource is actually returning records? if you do var myData = GetData([query]).ToList(); and put a breakpoint, does myData actually have any records?

Comment: also, if you have more than one record in the master grid, you're going to keep overriding `countgrid` session variable with each iteration. If the last row has zero sub-records, `countgrid` will be zero

Comment: and finally, I'm not sure that the rows will exist yet in the child gridview, because you've only just databound it. You would be better to instead put the dataset in a variable (like I said above), bind to *that* and take the count of it for your session variable

Comment: yes i have more than one record in master grid view and your right it gets last child grid row count and it has  zero records so what the solution for this problem

Comment: i tried you code but give the following error gridview commandargument does contain definition for row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91214/discussion-between-jonathan-and-ayman).